getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND when I call fetch on www.api.github.com/user
I am trying to follow this guide from lucia
Here is the code :
tokens = await github.validateAuthorizationCode(code);
 
const githubUserResponse = await fetch('https://www.api.github.com/user', {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${tokens.accessToken()}`
            }
        });

I can run  nslookup www.api.github.com/  ok
But if I  run nslookup www.api.github.com/user ,  I see error : ****** UnKnown can't find www.api.github.com/user: Non-existent domain***
in windows 11 , I tried adding this to hosts but it did not help :
127.0.0.1       localhost
Any suggestions?

https://api.github.com/, drop the www, who told you to put it there?

Thank you so much. The documentation is accurate - it was my mistake.
